# How does $\langle 1/t\rangle$ denote a rate?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, kinematics

As a preface I should mention I am a mathematician and not a physicist, so I apologize if this question is elementary. I am going through an old paper of mathematical physics that I have been assigned to read, and they claim $\langle 1/t\rangle $, where $\langle \cdot\rangle $ on an interval $[a,b]$ denotes the statistical average: $$\langle f\rangle = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f$$ is physically a rate. I can't see how the integral of the inverse of a time variable is a rate. Using the above definition, again on an interval $[a,b]$ we obtain $\langle 1/t\rangle = \frac{\log(b/a)}{b-a}$ which looks unlike any "rate" I have ever seen.

Comment: Which old paper? Which page?

Comment: Forgetting the algebra for a moment, $\langle \frac{1}{t} \rangle$ clearly has dimensions (or units if you want to think of it that way) of $1$ over time, or per unit time, which sounds like every rate I've ever heard of. But more context would be helpful, what is the specific probability measure that this is with respect to (uniform is fine too) ?

Comment: @NinadMunshi This is what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @Semoi will do :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algebraic formula aside, we can see that $\langle \frac{1}{t} \rangle$ has dimensions of time$^{-1}$, or per unit time, which is a rate. As @Semoi pointed out in the comments we can look at your algebraic formula as well for a uniform probability measure:

$$\left\langle\frac{1}{t}\right\rangle_{\operatorname{Unif}([a,b])} = \frac{1}{b-a}\log\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$$

$b-a$ has dimensions of time, which means the first term encapsulates the correct dimensionality for the whole expression. $\log\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$ is a dimensionless constant because we are dividing by two quantities that have the same units and "directions" (while time units will only have one direction to point, you can get dimensionless units by dividing lengths that point in different directions, for example a radian is one "meter per meter" where the numerator is the arc length of a circle which points angularly and the denominator is the radius which points radially).